# Оптимизация размера входных данных и структуры векторов для Hopfield нейронных сетей

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, сжатие, распознавание-образов

Здравствуйте уважаемое сообщество!

Я работаю с Hopfield нейронными сетями и столкнулся с рядом вопросов, касающихся масштабирования и подготовки данных. Надеюсь, здесь мне смогут помочь.

1. **Объем обрабатываемых данных:** Имеется ли ограничение на размер входных данных для Hopfield сетей? У меня есть бинаризированные векторы длиной 100 000 элементов, и я не уверен, как эффективно их использовать. Существует ли рекомендуемая длина входных векторов?
2. **Сжатие данных:** Возможно ли применить какие-либо алгоритмы сжатия данных для уменьшения размера входных векторов, не потеряв в качестве работы сети?
3. **Структура входных и выходных данных:** Входной вектор должен быть единичным значением или же это может быть набор векторов, объединенных в одну ячейку? Аналогичный вопрос касается выходных данных.

Благодарю за внимание и заранее благодарен за любую помощь!